# About means of positive definite matrices

Tags: matrices, inequalities

This question is related to this [recent one](https://mathoverflow.net/q/196460).

Recall that on the cone $SPD_n$ of $n\times n$ symmetric positive definite matrices, there are various notions of means, which extend the same notions already known for positive scalars: arithmetic, geometric, harmonic. In addition, they satisfy the same order:
$$m_H(A,B)\le m_G(A,B)\le m_A(A,B).$$

> I wander whether the following kind of mean is known. I call it the *cofactor-mean*, denoted $m_C(A,B)$, but shall be happy to adopt a well-established terminology.

Let $A\mapsto \hat A$ denote the cofactor map, and $B\mapsto \check B$ its inverse. For positive definite symmetric matrices, $\hat A=(\det A)A^{-1}$ and $\check B=(\det B)^{\frac1{n-1}}B^{-1}$. The cofactor-mean is
$$m_C(A,B)=\widehat{\frac12(\check A+\check B)}.$$
(Apology: the widehat is not wide enough, it should cover the fraction $\frac12\,$.)

It satisfies the following inequality
$$m_H(A,B)\le m_C(A,B).$$